# An arcane property of independent countries

Tags: geography, knowledge

The following alphabetical list contains independent countries with a certain arcane property. (The list is complete to the best of my knowledge).

> Algeria, Cambodia, Croatia, El Salvador, ????????,  Germany, ????????,
>     Serbia, South Africa, Spain, Sri Lanka, Switzerland, United Arab Emirates

Which countries have been replaced by questionmarks?
What is the arcane property?

Comment: Is the property uniquely present for this set of countries?

Comment: The list is complete to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm correct, the "arcane property" is arguable for a number of countries.  My best guess at the missing countries:

> Equatorial Guinea and Samoa

The "arcane property" seems to be

> Countries whose TLD (internet top-level-domain) starts with a different letter than the common English name of the country.
> .dz   Algeria
> .kh   Cambodia
> .hr   Croatia
> .sv   El Salvador
> .gq   Equatorial Guinea
> .de   Germany
> .ws   Samoa
> .rs   Serbia
> .za   South Africa
> .es   Spain
> .lk   Sri Lanka
> .ch   Switzerland
> .ae   United Arab Emirates

Several other countries could also qualify.  For example:

> .tl   East Timor
> .kp   North Korea (a.k.a. Democratic People's Republic of Korea) (neither name starts with a "K")